# JPA: Message + Notification DB Architecture

Tags: java, entity-framework, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

So I am building a web app for an office, front-end, back ends, mobility, client accounts, online registration, employees accounts, admin accounts ... the whole nine yards.

One of my major concerns (since I havent done it before) is the user entity interaction.
For now I have defined 4 methods with which a User Entity can interact with other Users.

1) Messages (to and from User ... to single or multiple User)

2) Notification( from back-end to User)

3) Task(to and from User ... to single or multiple User)

4) Invitation (to and from User ... to single or multiple User)

(an XMPP chat engine will be introduced, that needs logging, but thats on a later note)

I decided it would be outrageous to implement a com protocol for each type, so I created sort of an abstraction layer (please dont kill me over that one, but thats how I feel about it)

So within each User there will be 2 key lists

```
 private <Key> Sent_Parcels;
 private <Key> Received_Parcels;
```

These are just Array Lists that point to Parcel Entities (the abstraction Layer) which will contain

```
private Key Sender;   // Key of Sender User Entity
private List<Key>Recipients;   // List of Keys of Recipients
private Type type;   // Enum of Type : Message, Notification, Task, Invitation
private Key Payload;   // Key of the payload object: Message Entity, Notification Entity ...
```

Now standard creation, persistence, notification stuff ... no worries at all, since its a single com protocol, for different payloads ... dont care from this point as I can filter by Parcel Type so ...

HOWEVER, here are some major concerns(Keeping in mind large scale implementation):

1) Assuming Sender and all recipients decided to delete a payload. That means that all Parcel Entities created that point to this payload is gone ... how do I find payloads that aren't required anymore by anyone to delete them and save precious, expensive storage on GAE datastore.

2) I am pretty sure its not that simple to implement a com system between users, so I would LOVE if some expert on the subject would come along and tell me that is completely rubbish, here is how its done.

3) I have chosen this method because having duplicate tiny parcel entities, single payloads is better that having duplicate LARGE payloads (that are exactly the same) for each User participant in the com operation. However, having duplicate payloads will mean that if a user deletes it, good and well, dont have to go digging for who still owns the payload as he was the only entity owning it, on the other hand, I feel its such a waste of space

All comments and suggestions are welcomed ... Thanks alot guys for everything !!

Comment: Forgot Something Important !! ... Would be very nice to implement a read before/still new sort of thing ... like emails. So any thoughts on the subjects as to how it can be done ... would be super super nice adding the functionality of sending notification to Sender upon parcel open

Comment: Sending a notification : that's just programatically creating a new notification when a recipient opens a "Parcel"

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm not a "com system expert" by any means, I can probably help you with the datastore.

What you're doing right now is putting a relational data model in the datastore -> what's the point?
The datastore is not faster than RDBMS at making "joins", and actually you will have to spend most of your time fetching "relationships".

You need to see your problem from two different angles depending on what database system you use:

- Relational database: A Parcel is your base entity, and you create relationships that associates it with Users. You only remove "links" between Parcels and Users when someone deletes the parcel.
- Datastore: `User` is your base entity, and `Parcel`s only exist from a user's perspective: parcels sent, parcels received. Think of it as your Gmail client: the same "email" is actually duplicated in the senders' "sent mails" and the recipient's "inbox". If the sender removes the email, it has no effect on the recipient, vice versa.

In my opinion you are in this weird zone between clear "SQL" and "NoSQL", and I would not commit to the datastore without thinking thoroughly about that same old question : **what's your use case?** :)

---

**If you're making a user oriented messaging app like whatsapp or doodle**

the datastore is a nice option because of the scalability.
Your point **3)** is the best approach: you will need to duplicate your data so you can retrieve it fast for a given user, without joins.

```
/** Root entity : user */
@Entity
class User {
   @Id
   Key key;

   @Basic
   String name;

   @OneToMany
   List<UserReceivedParcel> inbox;

   @OneToMany
   List<UserSentParcel> sent;
}

/** User's child entity : Received parcels */
class UserReceivedParcel {
   @Id
   Key userReicevedParcelKey;

   /** Sender key AND duplicate properties to prevent running another query */
   @Persistent String senderKey;
   @Persistent String senderName;


   @Persistent String parcelType;
   /** Message data */
   @Persistent String messageContent;
   @Persistent Date sentDate;
}

/** User's child entity : Sent parcels */
class UserSentParcel {

   /** Recipient Key AND Attributes */
   @Persistent String recipientKey;
   @Persistent String recipientName;

   /** ... (message data) */

}
```

---

**If you're making a company messaging system**

you may probably need to run queries and have relationships going every direction. Google Cloud SQL (or any other RDBMS) might actually be a better fit... especially since the scale can be handled with good design. Don't underestimate the cost of doing reports without SQL queries on the datastore.

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable advice !! Considering your advice, I will probably stick to the datastore option for User Communication, but since you seem to have a firmer grip than I do on the SQL vs NoSQL, my real nightmare is business analytics. There will be an online store as well, that will display ads to users based on profile criteria, demographics and so on. Also intelligence system for email analytics (success rate of products sent out in email flyers), that should populate the best profiles to target with certain products, based on previous experience.

Comment: So I would really like to discuss some details and get advice on the general architecture aspects. I dont need rocket science NASA stuff here, just a decent enough model to get started without having to get an onsite solution from IBM

Comment: That's one daunting task you have out there, I hope you have a good team with you! Well analytics and "NoSQL" datastores are at the heart of "big data" issues. What you need to realize is that a major part of your data processing on the datastore (and most so called "NoSQL" databases) will be manual: to make it clear, you will have to put together some kind of job that programmatically queries your entities, parse, process, sum, whatever you need. Maybe have a look at MapReduce : https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be re-inventing a wheel called email with attachments and collaboration software ;-)

1) Consider implementing Delete as a move to a "Trash Can" recipient to simplify tracking items to be deleted.  [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) is more suitable for large "Parcels" (attachments), leaving plenty of Datastore space for the metadata.

2) no idea what you mean by a com protocol.  Communication?  Component?  REST and JSON are increasingly popular for the client-server link.  Channels would be the AppEngine way to deliver real time push notifications.

3) Apart from extremes like video files, space is cheaper than processing time or bandwidth.  The NoSQL way is to duplicate the data into a copy per recipient in order to avoid lookup or join operations.  Implement a per recipient storage quota to prevent their space usage from growing endlessly.

Comment: First of all thanks for the insight !! I love the trash can idea (and honestly feeling a bit dumb for not figuring this one out alone). Also wondering if there is a customizable java framework for sort of running a local email server (not through external servers and not receiving mail for external servers ... u get my point)

Comment: Third, I ment communication operation, its just the process name I am using (sorry if it meant something else) ... I am using REST and JSON, however, I am not sure if Channels provide upstream (does it??) I though of implementing a client side xmpp using strophe first for real time notifications and second as a foundation for chatting ... third, all 3 (User A chatting with User B and my notification servelet) could be logged in to a third party free jabber/xmpp server, thus cutting down my bill, rather than making it all local (so basically out sourcing chat) ... What do u think about that ??